# Get last mysql record only from a column

Tags: mysql

This is my existing table

```
 id   name  version
| 1 |  a   | 1.1 |
| 2 |  b   | 2.1 |
| 3 |  c   | 3.1 |
| 4 |  d   | 1.2 |
| 5 |  e   | 4.1 |
```

how can I write a query to generate results where i will return all records but only the last record in the column version is selected like below?

```
 id   name  version
| 4 |  d   | 1.2 |
| 2 |  b   | 2.1 |
| 3 |  c   | 3.1 |
| 5 |  e   | 4.1 |
```

Comment: Please include table names and columns.

Comment: Additionally, your result doesn't make sense, as the row `d` has `5` as its id, but in the results it has 1 as its id.

Comment: You logic is not clear,unless in the desired results you mean 4 insted of 1

Comment: `| 4 | d | 1.2 |` explain how it doesn't include

Comment: @NewbeeDev the first table is the base, the second table is the results of the query. If you find the row in the first table with `d` and compare that with the results table, row `d` you will notice the `4` has changed to a `1`.

Comment: @Mihai and JosephGarrone , corrected the question. thank you.

Comment: Explain what it is you want. As it stands, all I can deduce is that you want the results, ordered by the 3rd column where the first column is greater than 1

Comment: edited the question @Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you prefer a slightly less laborious solution...

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM t x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MAX(grade) grade
         FROM t
        GROUP 
           BY FLOOR(grade)
     ) y
    ON y.grade = x.grade
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f17db1/16

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit laborious but it can be done

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY REPLACE(grade,'.','')*1 DESC),',',1) as id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(letter ORDER BY REPLACE(grade,'.','')*1 DESC),',',1) as letter,
  MAX(grade) as grade
FROM
  t
  GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(grade,'.',1)
  ORDER BY REPLACE(grade,'.','')*1
```

Assuming the last column is float you can use ORDER BY lastcol directly

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f17db1/14)

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`id` int, `letter` varchar(7), `grade` varchar(55))
;

INSERT INTO t

VALUES
    (1, 'a', '1.1'),
    (2, 'b', '2.1'),
    (3, 'c', '3.1'),
    (4, 'd', '1.2'),
    (5, 'e', '4.1')
```

Comment: hey @Mihai, that is perfect, thank you so much. You're great in MYSQL

Comment: A bit laborious? I'll say!